# FFmpeg concatenate video and add watermark

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have command to overlay two video one on other.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "movie= overlay.mov [a]; [1][a]scale2ref[2nd][ref];[2nd][ref]overlay=0:0 [c]"  output.mp4
```

Now I want to add water watermark and concatenate a new video `append.mov` in above command. I have found a command to add watermark.

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" outputwatermark.mp4
```

But I want to merge both the command and also need to concatenate `append.mov` to `output.mp4`.

Also above overlay two video command takes too long time to process if video size is large. Any suggestion on that(should not affect quality of video)?

I tried following command to concatenate video.

```
ffmpeg -i abc.mp4 -i ../input/overlay2.mov append.mp4
```

The video was not concatenate, below is the output.

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'abc.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:37.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 474 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540 [SAR 3:4 DAR 4:3], 324 kb/s, 1k fps, 1k tbr, 16k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '../input/overlay2.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2020-03-27T16:32:23.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:37.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3519 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), argb(progressive), 640x352, 3295 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 20:11, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-27T16:32:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Animation
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #1:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-27T16:32:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
File 'append.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] using SAR=3/4
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] profile High, level 5.2
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'append.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 960x540 [SAR 3:4 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 1k fps, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame=37399 fps=378 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2138kB time=00:00:37.39 bitrate= 468.4kbits/s speed=0.378x    
video:1454kB audio:221kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 27.624002%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] frame I:150   Avg QP:11.47  size:  1655
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] frame P:9423  Avg QP:14.43  size:    52
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] frame B:27826 Avg QP:17.67  size:    27
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0% 99.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] mb I  I16..4: 94.0%  4.3%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.9%  L0:54.5% L1:45.5% BI: 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] 8x8 transform intra:4.8% inter:84.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 1.6% 2.3% 2.0% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] i16 v,h,dc,p: 96%  0%  3%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 58%  9% 28%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 38% 22% 15%  4%  4%  5%  5%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] i8c dc,h,v,p: 97%  1%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] Weighted P-Frames: Y:1.9% UV:1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] ref P L0: 86.3%  8.4%  4.5%  0.8%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] ref B L0: 75.4% 24.0%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] ref B L1: 98.1%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7ff35a012200] kb/s:318.42
[aac @ 0x7ff35a013a00] Qavg: 152.336
```

Comment: Need to see info about your inputs. Info can be seen with `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i overlay.mov -i append.mov`. Copy and paste the resulting log output into your question.

Comment: @llogan I have pasted my output as told by you. Your command was giving error `At least one output file must be specified`. So I updated the same. I hope you meant the same. If you want me add output without output video, please let me know.

Comment: You overwrote `append.mp4`. I wanted you to execute the command that I provided. The `At least one output file must be specified` was expected and could have been ignored (I almost mentioned that). I wanted info on your ffmpeg and the info about your inputs. Now info for the original `append.mp4` is missing, but it is needed for me to make an answer you can copy and paste.